# Lens arrangement for laser tag?

Tags: optics

I’m working on a laser tag game using IR LEDs and demodulation ICs. The trick is to force the gun to be aimed accurately at the center of the target. I’m willing to experiment, but I don’t really know much about lenses and focusing or collimating light.

The IR wavelength is ~940 nm, the modulation is 40 kHz. Targets will be 2 - 8 m away from the emitter. How much can I tighten up the emitted beam with a combination of tube and lens, using cheap parts (cheap plastic off-the-shelf lenses)?

The emitter can sit fairly far back in a narrow tube (10 - 20 cm), although shallower is better.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how I can tinker and arrive at a good solution (not to mention sources for cheap plastic lenses)? I found this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162119/how-do-i-find-the-right-lens-for-my-laser), which probably answers my question, but I feel a bit lost reading through the answers.

(I had asked this question over on the Physics SE, but was told this was probably a better forum.)

Comment: Although +/- 3 degree FOV Near-IR diodes exist, why are you aiming the LED? Laser tag systems normally have a wide FOV LED as the target and the receiver is in the gun. That way, it is more straightforward for the target to identify itself, you don't need to emit a narrow beam of potentially hazardous light and can hit the same target simultaneously with multiple guns.

Comment: Maybe my understanding is outdated, but I thought that narrow beam of potentially hazardous light was the way; I recall limits on how long one was allowed to emit (enforced by the circuits not the player).  Certainly possible to do it the other way around with the 'gun' being the sensor but not the way I recall seeing it.

Comment: It’s LED light (not actually laser), quite diffuse, isn’t it? In any case, putting the emitter in the target I think will address the aiming problem quite nicely. In this application multiple shooters wasn’t really a concern, but it fixes that problem too. Great suggestion.

Comment: It is diffuse but consider your TV's remote control works just fine and isn't focused nearly as much as your laser tag. It's not like you are going to be able to focus non-coherent LED light like a laser anyways. You just need to find a photodiode or phototransistor already equipped with a with a focusing lens for a narrow FOV. If that proves insufficient, then start looking at external optics (because that is a can of worms).

Comment: May I suggest you read up on how existing systems work before "reinventing the wheel" ?

Answer (score 1):

https://openlasertag.org/language/en/optical-emmiter-tube/

Basically what you want to do is to choose a lens that optimally utilizes the IR LED's emitted light. To do so, you calculate the ideal distance from lens using the LED's angle of half intensity and the lens radius. Then find a lens with the closest focal length to the ideal distance. There's many inexpensive lenses in many shapes and sizes available on Aliexpress and similar sites.